# Accuracy for Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, keras-layer

I am experementing molecular activity prediction as regression model in keras.

```
x_train.size=6252312
x_train.shape=(1452, 4306)
y_train.shape=(1452, 1)
y_train.size=1452

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation = "relu",  input_shape=(4306,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(25, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))
 model.compile(
optimizer="adam",
loss="mse",
)
model.summary()
# Train the model
model.fit(
 x_train,
 y_train,
 batch_size=500,
 epochs=900,
 validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
 shuffle=True
)
```

I run this two or three times, same code, but it show different r2 accuracy-why it shows different accuracy

```
 1452/1452 [==============================] - 0s 218us/step - loss: 0.5770 - val_loss: 0.1259 
R2-score: 0.47 
    1452/1452 [==============================] - 1s 411us/step - loss: 0.5882 - val_loss: 0.1281 
R2-score: 0.48
    1452/1452 [==============================] - 0s 332us/step - loss: 0.4917 - val_loss: 0.1154 
R2-score: 0.52
```

How to get the training accuracy.. When training model it shows only loss and val_ loss

And, any suggestion how to improve model accuracy

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accuracy makes no sense for a regression problem, it is a metric only valid for classification. You are already using the R2 score which behaves similarly than accuracy but for regression problems. You can also use the mean absolute error (mae).

Comment: Is the neural network nature that it show different values when we run many times and is that we have to maintain the training and testing accuracy in same range to make good model and for knowing training accuracy can we use- model.predict(x_train) and to take r2 value. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
model.compile( optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=['here you add your metrics'])
```

Adequate metrics for regression can be found [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/). Below is a list of those available in keras:

- **Mean Squared Error**: mean_squared_error, MSE or mse
- **Mean Absolute Error**: mean_absolute_error, MAE, mae
- **Mean Absolute Percentage Error**: mean_absolute_percentage_error, MAPE, mape
- **Cosine Proximity**: cosine_proximity, cosine

You can have your own custom metrics as well.

Comment: Thank you..Could you please tell me the scale of these metrics which I do not understand.. In the link,I saw the example - Epoch 100/100
0s - loss: 9.6515e-05 - mean_squared_error: 9.6515e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0084 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 3.3847 - cosine_proximity: -1.0000e+00 --------------- In this, "loss" is defined as mse and the metrics is also 'mse'-  both are same right and what range does the keras express the mse,mae,mape,cosine..